# Solving a cubic diophantine in integers $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 10^{2k}a + 10^{k}b + c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I wish to solve a cubic diophantine in integers. Here it is
$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 10^{2k}a + 10^{k}b + c$ for $k = 1,2,3...$

I tried using the identity that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = (a+ b+ c ) ( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 – ab – bc – ca ) + 3abc$, but got nowhere.

I also tried the following steps

$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - c = 10^{2k}a + 10^{k}b$

$a^3 - 10^{2k}a + b^3 - 10^{k}b + c^3 - c = 0$

$a(a^2 - 10^{2k}) + b (b^2 - 10^{k}) + c(c^2 - 1) = 0$

One thing that I have noticed is that all 3 digit Armstrong Numbers do satisfy this property. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Diophantine Equations with variable exponents tend to be extremely difficult to address.  When you posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617883/solving-a-cubic-equation-over-integers#4617883) before, you mentioned one infinite family of solutions.  I would also suggest searching for isolated solutions....solutions not part of some (apparent) infinite family.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your help. I have actually found a sequence on the OEIS that deals with these patterns http://oeis.org/A056733

Comment: Any suggestions?